# Chinese handwriting input method crash on iOS8.1

Tags: crash, handwriting, ios8.1

If user is using Chinese handwriting input method. After he typed anything and select candidates my app crashes. This only happens on iOS8.1 and only with the handwriting input method on my app. Other apps will not crash.

The crash log gives the information that:

2014-10-22 14:45:10.269 App[524:170755] -[UIKBBlurredKeyView candidateList]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16ff44b0

Answer (score 0):

Found the reason.

I have overridden touchesBegan method of UIScrollView in a category.